# Making 2 clocks with phase shift

Tags: clock, phase-shift

I'm trying to create 2 clocks with phase shift for 1/4 cycle time:

```
    Start
    V 
        ____      ____
C1   __|    |____|    |____
     ____      ____      __
C2  |    |____|    |____|
```

So after a reset or connecting to the power supply two quartz oscillators start with this configuration. I have the idea that I could use a single oscillator and maybe a counter that would define these two clocks.

Comment: A single clock running at 4X (or greater) than your desired output frequency and a couple of flip flops or a counter and some misc logic would do it.  Why don't you take a stab at it and get back to us.  You can just add to your question.

Comment: Hint - a 4X clock, a 2 bit counter, and a 4-bit shift register is all you need.

Comment: Is the phase important that there is always rising edge on C2 first and then C1? A clock with 2X the frequency of one square wave ahould be enough.

Comment: 2X clock with negative clock edge JK and positive clock edge JK or D.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a clock with 2 times the frequency of the output square wave.

Divide the original clock down by two with a D flip flop to get half-speed output.

Invert the original clock, and drive another D flip flop with it, which takes in the previous half-speed clock as data, and then it outputs the delayed half-speed clock 90 degrees later.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have a master clock running 4X faster then C1/C2 then you must rely on analog circuitry to generate the 1/4 clock delay. Then use a [Delay-Locked Loop](http://www.seas.ucla.edu/brweb/papers/Journals/BR_SSCM_3_2018.pdf) to keep the two clocks synchronized with the 1/4 clock difference.

You need to recognize that two crystal oscillators will **not** have exactly the same frequency, even if the crystals have the same part number. Sooner or later you will have to deal with that.

Answer (score 1):

> I have ideas that i could use 1 oscillator and maybe counter that would define this 2 clocks.

That's how its normally done, a 4x clock oscillator.
followed by 2 flip-flops forming a 2 stage Johnson counter.